# How to Correct Anchor

Tags: html

```html
<center>&gt;<p style="text-align: center"><a href="#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5">New Prototype Site Features are easily referenced at http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5 !</a></p></center>
```

I still do not have sufficient reputation to add the complete reference list.  However, the main reference is:

http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html

Additional references can be found at:

http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/technology/stephen-elliott/stack-overflow-questions/correcting-anchor-references

There you can find at the bottom the original sources listed.

```
Update in response to the first comment:  I tried "http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5" in my browser window and it automatically updated that to "http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5" and did not go to the anchor.  I am unable also to get the comment author's suggestion to work too: it is currently featured on the homepage http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/ but the browser does not go to the anchor when typed in at the top URL field.
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and properly explain what you're trying to do. "How to correct anchor" is not a question.

Comment: From what I understand from your question is that anchor tag isn't working, it's because you've not used `href` properly 
`<a href="http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5 !">New Prototype Site Features are easily referenced at http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5 !</a>` <br> this should fix your problem.

Comment: Yash I appreciate your reply.  However, I basically copied and pasted what you suggested on my website http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/ and it did not work.  The website automatically forwards to http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/  I am trying next to add the wordpress part to the name where it automatically redirects.

Comment: How to Correct Anchor http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5 was the original title.  "How can the Anchor ... be Corrected" was shortened because of the Limitation in Title Length.  In this case, the website itself is central to the issue.  I suppose now that it is redirecting to http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress is the core of the issue.

Comment: By the way, I read, "http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask" and I appreciate the suggestion.  It was a nice article.

Comment: I put an update about the suggestion in the main article; it did not work for me yet!

Comment: I am trying the approach of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor and it has a different approach.  I am trying this with h3 and seeing how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to try a different reference.  Wikipedia has the way that it is currently done.  The main reference that I used seemed to document the older style of getting to an anchor.

```html
http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/#contents
and http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/#contents
```

both work the same.  The main link http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/#contents redirects automatically to http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/#contents

However, contents has to be formatted within the page (I am using the NewMag Pro theme) as

```html
    <h4 id="contents">Table of contents:  try </h4> 
  
    <a href="http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com#contents">see contents</a>
```

Using id instead of the simple #anchor seems to be the key.  It works with GET posts variables also.  Something to be aware of is that - if logged in to Wordpress - the anchors do not necessarily work, perhaps depending on the theme and plugins used.  Log out of wordpress or launch the site in a private window to get the expected behavior.

I ended up with these three variations of the link.  (I put #contents there just to support the stackoverflow post here for people to reference.)

```html
New York Business Review – The Latest in Business for Today
http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/?carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5=4#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5

New York Business Review – The Latest in Business for Today
http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5

New York Business Review – The Latest in Business for Today
http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/#contents

New York Business Review – The Latest in Business for Today
http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/?carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5=4#anchor_carousel_edit_url_for_newspro-5
```